# Setting up an ionic tabbed application

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I'm relatively new to ionic, so here I want to create my first ionic application from scratch.

I'm just trying to get the scaffolding of a basic tabbed bar application up and running. For this I've created an app folder inside the www and started up with my own app.js. This is my app.js

```
angular.module("PelvicRehabLog", ["ionic"])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
  });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

});
```

I've also created a home folder inside my app folder with the following home.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Log</h1>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-energized tabs-icon-top">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon="ion-home" href="#">
    <ion-view name="tab-dash"></ion-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon="ion-home" href="#">
    <ion-view name="tab-dash"></ion-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

And I've changed the relevant reference in the index.html

```
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="PelvicRehabLog">
```

At this stage I'm expecting to see a basic tabbed bar application, with two tabs. But all I see is a blank screen. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are u using apache cordova? It can be pretty easy to set up with the visual studio plugin. You just copy pase the template in after cheking env variables

Comment: I'm on linux, and in any case how does the IDE matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some child states under your abstract state.

**Abstract States**

"... An abstract state can have child states but cannot get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated ..."

read this [article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) or check example of app.js from ionic build:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {   
$stateProvider
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
url: '/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
// Each tab has its own nav history stack:
.state('tab.dash', {
url: '/dash',
views: {
  'tab-dash': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
    controller: 'DashCtrl'
  }
}
})
.state('tab.chats', {
  url: '/chats',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
      controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
    }
  }
 })
 .state('tab.chat-detail', {
  url: '/chats/:chatId',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
      controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.account', {
url: '/account',
views: {
  'tab-account': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
    controller: 'AccountCtrl'
  }
}
});
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` in your `body` tag inside your `index.html`. Cross check your console for errors.